# Inline div alignment problems in Webkit?

Tags: html, css

If you check out [antonpug.com](http://antonpug.com/)

You'll notice that in Firefox and Opera, the header states Title (Search Icon) (Menu)

However in Chrome and Safari, it seems like both elements refuse to be inline and you get something like this:

(Search Icon)
Anton Pugachevsky  (Menu)

I have been pondering this one for a while, any ideas why this might be happening?

Comment: Seems to be because `.navbar-header` is floated without an explicit width. Once you give it a width of f.e. 300px, it will display as you want.

Comment: If you want the 'search' to appear after the 'brand', could you not just reorder them in the HTML?  At the moment, search comes first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wish to make elements float properly in CSS you'll need to set the width of their container, or else the outer container will only gain a width of largest child element.

In your case simply set a width for .navbar-header and the elements will display inline.

If you wish the search to be on the left of the title then simply add float:left to the #search-icon.

For example

```
.navbar-header{ width:50%; }

.navbar-header #search-icon{ float:left; margin-right:30px; }
```

Comment: That fixes the problem at hand, but what happens now is that when you shrink the width to mobile-sized, you'll see that it's broken (menu button is not aligned to the right side of the screen, and the search button is mispositioned)

Comment: I fixed it. Had to use a media query to set the size to a fixed width when smaller than a certain size! Thanks